# Graph: Creating an event with attendees without sending the message/invite

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, office365api

I'm currently implementing a line of business application that helps users scheduling recurring events as well as managing the agenda of these events.
With code looking like the example provided bellow, we're creating the series all together.
Then looping on the instances we're updating the body of each instance to reflect the agenda generated for that particular day.
**The issue we're running into is that exchange and the graph are sending an email to all attendees at creation of the series and then on update of each instance**.
We'd like to have more control over that flow: creating the series (no email), updating the bodies (no email) and then send one (or many) emails for each instance. I couldn't find anything in [the documentation](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_post_events) around that.
Thanks for you help.

```
var updatingEvent = new Event
{
     Subject = "test",
     Location = new Location { DisplayName = "Montreal" },
     IsAllDay = false,
     Start = getTimeZoneFromDateTime(DateTime.Now, tzLabel),
     End = getTimeZoneFromDateTime(DateTime.Now.AddHours(1), tzLabel),
     OnlineMeetingUrl = "someurl",
     Body = new ItemBody { Content = emailBody.HtmlBody, ContentType = BodyType.Html },
     ShowAs = FreeBusyStatus.Busy,
     Recurrence = new PatternedRecurrence
            {
                Range = new RecurrenceRange
                {
                    StartDate = new Date(DateTime.Now.Year, DateTime.Now.Month, DateTime.Now.Day),
                    Type = RecurrenceRangeType.Numbered,
                    NumberOfOccurrences = 3
                },
                Pattern = new RecurrencePattern
                {
                     Interval = 1,
                    Type = RecurrencePatternType.Daily
                }
            };
};
var updatedEvent = await client.Users[Settings.SkypeUserEmail].Calendar.Events.Request().AddAsync(updatingEvent);
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

It seems normal that if you put something on a calendar for someone else, they get notified. So I am not surprised you cannot suppress the message.

Can you not add the "attendees" until the final step? That way, they only get a message once you are ready.

Comment: I agree with you it makes sense in some way. It's just that in our scenario it doesn't play well because we might be going through several updates before the content is ready to be sent out. I guess we'll be able to work around that with the way we build things but having that capability would have simplified things a great deal

Comment: Whilst I can understand this, it does make it difficult for some use cases. We're currently moving from one email & calendar platform to O365 and are wanting to migrate all shared/group calendars. Users have already received these invites in the old platform, so it doesn't make sense for them to receive it again.